# Create / Add a new Document Set in Library from PowerApps Form

Tags: document-set, powerapp, modern-document-library

I have just created a new PowerApp form to create a new Document Set in my library.
The Fields are mapped fine but the Save button stays put site response bar in waiting 
From the Form settings i have enabled :
[image]

The Power App is opened automatically fine when the new Button and the ContentType selected.
[image]

PS: If I edit an existing DocSet it saves the records fine.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: slightly off topic but how did you wire this up?  my doc sets are created from another process, i simply need to leverage powerapps to conditionally show/hide fields in the doc set edit panel.   thx!

Comment: While creating Document Set through power apps, there is a limitation for **Name** field which is in View Mode only with mandatory (Primary key). So We might work around and looks for alternatives. I will update you, if found any solution.